# Map not appearing on events info pages

Tags: civievent, map

We are using a working API Google Key that is used to display maps on a site.

On the pages where we configure the map to display, such as in views, this works fine and the map appears as it should.

However, on the Civi events info page, the map is not appearing at all and there are no errors in the Google console.

I'm wondering if this has something to do with the geocoding, I realised that the scheduled job for Geocoding had failed every time in the past so I had a play around and got it to run successfully but it didn't geocode every address (about 1/3 were left).
Whether or not this is related is another matter but I thought I best include it.

Feel free to ask for more information if needed.

Comment: Can you confirm that the latitude and longitude fields are populated in the event location section of the event?

Comment: Can you also confirm that in the info and settings section of the event you have ‘Include Map to Event Location’ selected?

Comment: The settings are set to show a map, yes. In the database, most of the locations are filled in but not all

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Is there a solution?